# How do you use the meteor-accounts-t9n package?

Tags: javascript, meteor, package, translation

I'm once again attempting to use the meteor-accounts-t9n package and I'm seriously flipping out with the vague explanations provided in the package's [GitHub](https://github.com/softwarerero/meteor-accounts-t9n).

I added the package with meteor add meteor-accounts-t9n as well as the accounts-password and accounts-ui packages.

Then I created part of my usual project structure: client folder, server folder and lib folder.
I got nothing on server for now.

I configured my client html to be like:

```
<head>
  <title>t9nTest</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
    {{> loginButtons}}
</template>
```

My javascript is like:

```
Template.loginButtons.onRendered(function(){
    T9n.setLanguage("pt");
});
```

I've attempted with Meteor.startup as well.

I added a **t9n folder** under **lib**. On that folder I put a file called **pt.coffee** and put the entire portuguese structure available on the project's github.

**KEEP IN MIND THIS IS MY ONLY COFFESCRIPT FILE - I'M WANT TO USE JAVASCRIPT**

Still nothing. What am I missing? What is the appropriate usage of the package in order to translate the **accounts-ui loginButtons form**?

I also have gotten this error on the client-side: "**Uncaught Error: No such function: t9n"** when I attempt to directly convert a string returned by a helper function with `

> {{t9n textReturned}}

Comment: I use it and as far as I remember, you are not required to do much... Once you install it, you can set the language using `T9n.setLanguage("pt");` (which I am aware you did) and it just "works": all account-related texts are magically translated. Although I would not know about `accounts-ui`, as I am using [meteor-useraccounts](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core) instead. All I can say is that it works "as-is" with useraccounts.

Comment: Hmm... but meteor-useraccounts uses Iron Router... And I really don't want that (I prefer Carbon or Flow)

Comment: Yup that's the issue. You have to use meteor-useraccounts (useraccounts:core) but we don't want that. I'm going to try using tap:i18n and the regular accounts-ui. If you want to put this as the answer, I'll gladly aprove it.

Comment: Very well. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, in terms of translations for account-related UI elements (buttons, links, placeholders and so on), `meteor-accounts-t9n` is set to work with the [meteor-useraccounts](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core) packages. (core and framework-specific, such as [bootstrap](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/bootstrap), [foundation](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/foundation), [ratchet](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/ratchet)...)

With the meteor-useraccounts packages installed and in use (using `{{> atForm}}`), all you need to do is, like you said, install the meteor-accounts-t9n package:

```
$ meteor add softwarerero:accounts-t9n
```

And that's it, the translations should be in place according to the default language. All you need to do to change the language for your account elements is (here for portuguese):

```
T9n.setLanguage("pt");
```